# How to auto close an application?

Tags: java, android, accessibility

how to can I programmatically close a application example com.example
I have got to know this could be done with accessibility service with `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED` and  `performGlobalAction(AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_HOME);`
and now please guide me how can I perform this

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to close your own application:

You can close the app using `finishAffinity()` or `finishAndRemoveTask()` from API 21

**For Activity**

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=16 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<21) {
    finishAffinity();
} else {
    finishAndRemoveTask();
}
```

**For Fragments**

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=16 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<21) {
    getActivity().finishAffinity();
} else {
    getActivity().finishAndRemoveTask();
}
```

### If you want to close another application

You can only kill a process that has the same userID as your app or your app is a system app or your device is rooted.